# Launch a php script without form

Tags: php, html

I've never met such approach before, but I'm wondering why nothing happens after clicking the "Say hello" button.

```
<html>
<head>    
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myscript.php">Say hello</button>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<?php
echo "Hello";
?>
```

It would look very "bombastic" if I used the "form" markup construction in this case.
Could you point out my mistake? Or if my vision is totally hopeless, what are the unconventional ways to run the php script?

Comment: Code is not to "look bombastic".

Comment: You should apply css rules to an anchor tag that make it look exactly like a button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you using onclick? `onclick` executes javascript code.

Just link to the file

```
<a href="myscript.php">Say Hello</a>
```

If you must use javascript, you have to redirect to that page using something like `window.location`

Here's a [tutorial on redirecting with javascript](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php)

Answer (score 5):

Because `onclick` events evaluate JScript or JavaScript code, not file name. 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Answer (score -1):

onclick is a so called Event-Property. That expects javascript code by default.

this example is equivalent to including a js file with the content

```
test.php
```

that would raise an error as there is no object called test... You could put it in quotes which would make it a string and solve the problem... at least no error would be raised.

But back to your question: You don't launch a php script do you? with

```
<form method=GET action="scriptname.php">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

you tell your browser to open a php-file with additional informations from the form.
It is of course possible to communicate with a php file in the background, search for ajax in order to do that.

Comment: But I guess you just want to do the following:
`onclick="alert("hello!")`